# Accessing structure members in C

Tags: c, struct

Actually few hours back, I had posted a question but there was some error in my question (My bad!!). I want to access the members of a structure (profile_t) which is placed inside a structure (profile_datagram_t) and profile_t is a array of structs....

```
            struct profile_t
          {
            unsigned char length;
            unsigned char type;
            unsigned char *data;
          };

            typedef struct profile_datagram_t
         {
            unsigned char src[4];
            unsigned char dst[4];
            unsigned char ver;
            unsigned char n;
            struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];     
         } header;
```

Comment: Identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved by POSIX, so better not use them. There is actually no need to have the `struct` tag differently from the `typedef` name. `typedef struct header { .... } header;` would do well.

Answer (score 7):

This sets the length of the first profile in the headers to 10:

```
header h;
h.profiles[0].length = 10;
```